# Unable to queryselector HTML elements dynamically created by JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do my course project so I am a newbie to this.

The project is creating an emailing website.

So after listing the emails a user should be able to click on any email to view that email. But since the list of emails is dynamically generated by JS:

```
if (mailbox == "sent") {
    fetch('/emails/sent')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(emails => {

      for (let i=0; i<emails.length; i++) {
        const id = emails[i].id;
        const sender = emails[i].sender;
        const subject = emails[i].subject;
        const timestamp = emails[i].timestamp;
        document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML += `
        <div>
          <a href="#">
            <div data-id="${id}" class=" row email-box">
              <div class=" col-2 email-sender">${sender}</div>
              <div class="col-3 email-subject">${subject}</div>
              <div class="col-7 email-timestamp">${timestamp}</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>`;
      }
    })
  }
```

[image]

queryselector is not working:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('#emails-view > div:nth-child(2) > div').foreach(function(email) {
      email.onclick = function() {
        console.log('clicked')
      }
    });
  });
```

I tried this on a simple h3 thats also dynamically created and it still doesnt work.

```
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = `<h3 id="h3">${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;
```

```
  document.querySelector('h3').addEventListener('click', () => console.log('clicked'));
```

Here us the full code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // Use buttons to toggle between views
  document.querySelector('h3').addEventListener('click', () => console.log('clicked'));
  


  document.querySelector('#inbox').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('inbox'));
  document.querySelector('#sent').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('sent'));
  document.querySelector('#archived').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('archive'));
  document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click', compose_email);

  // By default, load the inbox
  load_mailbox('inbox');
});

function compose_email() {

  // Show compose view and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'block';

  // Clear out composition fields
  document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#compose-body').value = '';

  document.querySelector('#compose-form').onsubmit = () => {
    
    fetch('/emails', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
          recipients: document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value,
          subject: document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value,
          body: document.querySelector('#compose-body').value
      })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        // Print result
        console.log(result);
    })
    
    load_mailbox('sent')
    return false;    
  }
}

function load_mailbox(mailbox) { 

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('#emails-view > div:nth-child(2) > div').foreach(function(email) {
      email.onclick = function() {
        console.log('clicked')
      }
    });
  });

  // Show the mailbox and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';

  // Show the mailbox name
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = `<h3 id="h3">${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;

  if (mailbox == "sent") {
    fetch('/emails/sent')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(emails => {

      for (let i=0; i<emails.length; i++) {
        const id = emails[i].id;
        const sender = emails[i].sender;
        const subject = emails[i].subject;
        const timestamp = emails[i].timestamp;
        document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML += `
        <div>
          <a href="#">
            <div data-id="${id}" class=" row email-box">
              <div class=" col-2 email-sender">${sender}</div>
              <div class="col-3 email-subject">${subject}</div>
              <div class="col-7 email-timestamp">${timestamp}</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>`;
      }
    })
  }

  else if (mailbox == "inbox") {
    fetch('/emails/inbox')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(emails => {
    
      for (let i=0; i<emails.length; i++) {
        const id = emails[i].id;
        const sender = emails[i].sender;
        const subject = emails[i].subject;
        const timestamp = emails[i].timestamp;
        document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML += `
        <div>
            <div data-id="${id}" class=" row email-box">
              <div class=" col-2 email-sender">${sender}</div>
              <div class="col-3 email-subject">${subject}</div>
              <div class="col-7 email-timestamp">${timestamp}</div>
            </div>
        </div>`;
      }
    })
  }

  else if (mailbox == "archive") {
    fetch('/emails/archive')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(emails => {

      for (let i=0; i<emails.length; i++) {
        const id = emails[i].id;
        const sender = emails[i].sender;
        const subject = emails[i].subject;
        const timestamp = emails[i].timestamp;
        document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML += `
        <div>
          <a href="#">
            <div data-id="${id}" class="row email-box">
              <div class=" col-2 email-sender">${sender}</div>
              <div class="col-3 email-subject">${subject}</div>
              <div class="col-7 email-timestamp">${timestamp}</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>`;
      }
    })
  }
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelector('.email-box').addEventListener('click', () => console.log('clicked'));
  });

}

function view_email(id) { 

  fetch(`/emails/${id}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(email => {
    // Print email
    console.log(email);

    // ... do something else with email ...
  });
}
```

Comment: You probably want [event-delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)

Answer (score 0):

simply use event delegation:

```
const emailsView = document.querySelector('#emails-view');

//...

if (mailbox == "sent") 
  {
  fetch('/emails/sent')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(emails => 
    {
    for (let email of <emails) 
      {
      emailsView.innerHTML += `
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="email-infos">
            <div data-id="${email.id}" class="row email-box">
              <div class="col-2 email-sender">${email.sender}</div>
              <div class="col-3 email-subject">${email.subject}</div>
              <div class="col-7 email-timestamp">${email.timestamp}</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>`;
      }
    })
  }


  //...


emailsView.onclick = evt =>
  {
  let emailInfos = evt.target.closest('a.email-infos')

  if (!emailInfos) return

  console.log( emailInfos.querySelector('email-sender').textContent
  console.log( emailInfos.querySelector('email-subject').textContent
  console.log( emailInfos.innerText )
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Also for selector, try one of these, a variation of them, or put a `class name` on your desired target.

```
querySelectorAll('#emails-view .email-box')
querySelectorAll('#emails-view a')
querySelectorAll('#emails-view .clickable') // add a class name to your target
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: removed from solution

Comment: And what's wrong with OP's selector? Yours won't select the same elements

Comment: I don't see their selector working with indexes given.  Much easier to use a class name to target.